# vim: Opening a file and showing the last N opened files in N splits

Tags: vim

I am using vim (7.3) with a four way window split. I want to do the following:

Select a file to open. Put it in window 1. Move file that was occupying window 1 to window 2, 2->3, 3->4 and discard window 4 out of view (unless there are unwritten changes).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you ask but you may be able to pull ideas from it's source: https://github.com/spolu/dwm.vim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:topleft split file5 | wincmd b | close | wincmd t | wincmd =
```

Explanation: Do a `:split` at the top, so `file5` becomes the first window. All existing windows move down, but now there's one too many. To `:close` that, we go to the bottom window, close it, then back to the top. The last command makes all windows equally large again; this is not necessary when `'equalalways'` is set.

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question, so I will gladly accept it. Doesn't work for me because I have a four way grid split, but I will try to work that out (which will be hard due to vim's seeming inability to move windows between columns of my grid.)